# No matter what I do my image won't show, using html and css

Tags: html, css, image

I'm just just now starting out and this is my first project. No matter what I do my image won't show (only the top header image will), on the web-page it will show as broken or won't show at all.
I've tried:

- using a relative and absolute path
- different types of syntax (../../ - ../ - /)
- commenting out some css to see if that would change things
- using a completely different image

adding an image just always seemed so easy to me and I don't understand why this simple task can't be preformed. would love the help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Knitting Submission Form</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="./resources/css/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700|Montserrat:100,200,300" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poiret+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- resize icon or enter image -->
    <header>
        <h1>KNIT HUB</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h2>Knitting Submission Form</h2>
        <h2>Share and Join Our Community</h2>
    </header>
    <img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/8uTqI_KpC_Q">
    <img src="Knitting-Submission-Form/resources/images/gray yarn basket.jpeg">
    <div>
        <p>Name:<input type="text" placeholder="First Name/Nickname"></p>
        <label for="age" class="age">Age:</label>
        <select id="age-dropdown">
            <option value="" disable selected hidden>...Choose</option>
            <option value="1">12-19</option>
            <option value="2">20-29</option>
            <option value="3">30-39</option>
            <option value="4">40-49</option>
            <option value="5">50=59</option>
            <option value="6">60-69</option>
            <option value="7">70-79</option>
            <option value="8">80+</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <p>How much do you typically spend a year on knitting materials?</p>
        <span class="currencyinput">$<input type="text" name="currency"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h3>What's Your Knitting Skill Level?</h3>
        <input type="checkbox" class="skill-level" name="skill-level" value="interested">Interested, I like yarn and
        needles<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="skill-level" name="skill-level" value="beginner">Beginner, I know my knits and
        purls<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="skill-level" name="skill-level" value="intermediate">Intermediate, Knitting is my
        happy place<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="skill-level" name="skill-level" value="pro">Pro, I can dress myself in head to toe
        knits<br>
        <br>
    </div>



    <!-- find out "for" attribute-->
    <div>
        <form>
            <h3>How many years have you been knitting?</h3>
            <input type="radio" name="how-long" value="not-started">
            <label for="">I haven't started yet</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="how-long" value="getting-started">
            <label for="">Just getting started</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="how-long" value="1-3-years">
            <label for="">1-3 years</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="how-long" value="4-7-years">
            <label for="">4-7 years</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="how-long" value="8-14-years">
            <label for="">8-14 years</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="how-long" value="15+">
            <label for="age3">15+ years</label><br><br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <h3>How many times a week do you knit?</h3>
        <input type="radio" name="weekly" value="0-days">
        <label for="">hey, i'm not there yet</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="weekly" value="1-2-days">
        <label for="">1-2 days</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="weekly" value="3-4-days">
        <label for="">3-4 days</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="weekly" value="5-6-days">
        <label for="">5-6 days</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="weekly" value="60">
        <label for="age2">7 days, i knit in my sleep</label><br>
        </form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <h3 class="favorite-things">What are your favorite things to knit?</h3>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="favorites" value="hats">Hats<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="favorites" value="scarves">Scarves<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="favorites" value="shawls">Shawls<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="favorites" value="blankets">Blankets<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="favorites" value="gloves">Gloves<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="favorites" value="sweaters">Sweaters<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="favorites" value="socks">Socks<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="favorites" value="other">Other<br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h3>What's your favorite thing about knitting?</h3>

        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <textarea name="message" rows="12" cols="40">Be creative as you like.</textarea>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h3>Upload a photo of your latest creation below:</h3>
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
            <input type="submit">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Share</button>
        </form>
    </div>


</body>

</html>



body {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.1);
    margin-bottom: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

header {
    background: url("../images/pink heart yarn.jpeg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 670px;
    margin-right: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 90px;
    font-weight: 200;
    letter-spacing: .06em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}  

h2 {
  font-family: "Poiret One"; 
  font-weight: 200;
}

div {
    font-family: lora;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

}
.age {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -1px;
}

.currencyinput {
    border: 1px inset #ccc;
}
.currencyinput input {
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

URLs shouldn't contain literal spaces. Change the image file name to not have spaces (such as gray_yarn+basket.jpeg) or update the code to encode the spaces (gray%20yarn%20basket.jpeg).

Comment: thank you so much for the response...I tried that and it didn't work. :( I'm gonna make sure in the future though that I don't put spaces in